# History of mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics

Could anyone please suggest me a good book which explains the history of mechanics clearly in a way that the modern reader can comprehend without knowing a breadth of historical facts? Also a book of similar nature with regards to the development of the energy concept in mechanics would be a great help. Thanks.

( I have tried out books by Mach and Dugas but they seem to be covered in obscure references or author's opinions )

Comment: Dugas' book is still the more comprehensive...

Comment: See [list](https://www.google.it/search?q=history+of+mechanics&safe=active&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiw4Ly-kurSAhVIWBQKHRL3DF4Q_AUIDSgG&biw=1517&bih=708).

Comment: On work, see Agamenon Oliveira, [A History of the Work Concept](https://books.google.it/books?id=JcLEBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA1) (2014).